# PyQt: QDataWidgetMapper doesn't show any data in widgets

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a AbstractItemModel that I want to map to some widgets. In the constructor of the window I have:

```
    print("creating model")
    self.model = Model(self.cluster)
    print("creating mapper")
    self.mapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper()
    print("setting model")
    self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
    print("setting root index")
    self.mapper.setRootIndex(self.model.root_index())
    print("setting index")
    self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(0)
    print("mapping widgets")
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.realNameLineEdit, 1)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.emailLineEdit, 2)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.infoPlainTextEdit, 3)
    print("done")
```

This results in the following output:

```
creating model
Model.__init__()
Model.rowCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0x7faa2ff446a0,Model(0x17c6f50) )   at 0x7faa2d9ea4c8>) = 0
Model.rowCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0x7faa2ff446a0,Model(0x17c6f50) )   at 0x7faa2d9d2888>) = 1
creating mapper
setting model
setting root index
Model.root_index()
setting index
Model.rowCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2ff50d08>) = 2
Model.index(0, 0, <PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2ff50d08>)
Model.rowCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2d9ea608>) = 2
Model.columnCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2d9ea608>) = 4
mapping widgets
Model.index(0, 1, <PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2ff50d08>)
Model.rowCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2d9ea608>) = 2
Model.columnCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2d9ea608>) = 4
Model.index(0, 2, <PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2ff50d08>)
Model.rowCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2d9ea608>) = 2
Model.columnCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2d9ea608>) = 4
Model.index(0, 3, <PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2ff50d08>)
Model.rowCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2d9ea608>) = 2
Model.columnCount(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0) )  at 0x7faa2d9ea608>) = 4
done
```

For me that looks correct so far. But none of the mapped widgets display any data. Model.data() isn't even called at all (I have a print there too).

When I enter something in the realNameLineEdit and press return I get:

```
Model.setData(<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,1,0x7faa2da31908,Model(0x17c6f50) )   at 0x7faa2d9eadc8>, real name, 2)
```

Looks like editing goes through the mapper to the model correctly. So why doesn't displaying?

Comment: Connect a QTableView to the model and see if it in fact contains any data. And try calling `self.mapper.toFirst()`  **after** establishing mappings.

Comment: I have a QComboBox which shows the entries correctly (column 0). Also notice that rowCount() returns 2. Does `self.mapper.toFirst()` do anything other than `self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(0)`?

Comment: The *after* is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from comments for the sake of completeness:
`mapper.to First()`, `mapper.setCurrentIndex()` or similar must be called **after** column mappings were established for mappings to show any data.